# At what part of the vehicle should I aim my LAT / HAT / tank shell?

Tags: battlefield-2, project-reality

I'm not sure where to aim my weapon when shooting at armor vehicles in Project Reality. I mean, I realize that the front armor is the strongest while the (rarely accessible) underside armor is pretty weak. However, I'm not sure between the rest. Should I aim for the side armor, the tracks, the turret, the back side, the top, etc.?

And if there's no uniform armor behavior between different armored vehicles, is there anywhere I could find a guide for this basic "where to aim" question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The under side and rear armor is always the weakest to my knowledge. Followed by the side armor. The rear armor is where you'll want to aim, unless you have a way of hitting it's underside.

Comment: And do you know how the turret compares to the rest?

Comment: Sorry I don't, I'm not sure how sophisticated the engine behind the damage calculations is. I dout it's comparable.